# How to run script on startup and keep it running?

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, celery

I have 4 script files for start my django project. I want to run these scripts on background when system is up. I created 1 script that trigger others and i tried `sudo crontab -e` `@reboot /that/one/script.sh`. It is working on startup(i understand it because ports are open) but its not keep running in background. When i go to browser i can see nginx default page it is opening ports but my site doesnt keep working.

**script1**:
`celery -A MyProject flower --loglevel=info`

**script2**:
`uswgi --socket mysite.sock --module MyProject.wsgi --chmod-socket=666 --http :9090 --chdir /home/ubuntu/Desktop/project`

**script3**:
`celery worker --app=MyProject --loglevel=info --pool=gevent --concurrency=1000`

**script4**:
`celery beat -A MyProject -l DEBUG`.

Manually everything works good. So how can i run these scripts on startup and keep running on background without system login.

Comment: The most foolproof way is to set up Systemd unit files for them.

Comment: I agree with @AKX. Even in uwsgi doc you can see [example with systemd](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html) but you should find many other [examples with systemd and uwsgi](https://github.com/JacksonHill/systemd-uwsgi-example)

Answer (score 0):

This process, often referred to as *daemonization* is explained in details on a [dedicated "Daemonization" page](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html) in the Celery documentation.